# Trigger Error salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger

I try this trigger but it shows an error :

> Error:Apex trigger testTrigger caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: testTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate
>   caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: Sarah:
>   Trigger.testTrigger: line 22, column 1

This is the line 22:
`op.Contact__c= c.Name;`

Could you please help me to see where is the issue.

```
trigger testTrigger on Opportunity (after update) {
List conList=new List(); List cons = new List(); 
    for(opportunity opp : trigger.new)
    { 
        if(String.isBlank(opp.field__c))
        { 
            opp.addError('missing field'); 
        }
        else if(!String.isBlank(opp.field__c)) 
        { 
            cons.add(opp.field__c); 
        }
    } 
         if(cons.size() == 0) return;

    for(Contact c : [Select Id, account.Name, Name, field__c From Contact where field__c in :cons])
    {
        for(Opportunity op : (List<Opportunity>)Trigger.New)
        {
            if (op.field__c == C.field__c)
            {
                op.Contact__c= c.Name;
                op.account.Name=c.account.Name;          
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will never get that error message in an `after update` context, it's too late by that point ..

Comment: @EricSSH Lots of issues here...

Comment: @EricSSH you could if you attempt to set a lookup to a string value as the error happens first. The final exception happens after the trigger finishes IIRC

Answer (score 2):

`op.Contact__c` has to be Id - `c.Id`

Also, you can't update `Account.Name` on `Opportunity`. You can only modify `Account` field which is a Lookup to `Account` and has to be `Account` record Id

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61770/discussion-on-answer-by-oleksiy-trigger-error-salesforce).

Answer (score 2):

You may need to do several corrections in your code as others commented. Few are listed below

**Change the trigger event to BEFORE UPDATE because you are writing values on the triggered records(opportunity). Field is not writable in After Update event for triggered records.**

**Avoid Nested FOR Loop. Use map to avoid nested FOR loop, which will increase your code performance.**

**Account.Name on opportunity cannot be written directly on opportunity record. Link the account record to the opportunity.**

Please find the below code reference for your doubts.

```
trigger testTrigger on Opportunity (before update) {
    List cons = new List(); 
    Map<String,Contact> mapOfContacts = new Map<String,Contact> ();
    for(opportunity opp : trigger.new){ 
        if(String.isBlank(opp.field__c)){
            opp.addError('missing field'); 
        }
        else if(String.isNotBlank(opp.field__c)) { 
            cons.add(opp.field__c); 
        }
    } 
    // Your Logic seems to be incorrect, If field__c in Contact is NOT Unique, the in your CONTACT query, you may get more than one contact record.
    // And hecne you may link a random contact record on Contact__c field. Work on this area to link the correct contact record if field__c is not unique.
    // Avoid Nested FOR loop. Using map to avoid Nested FOR Loop. if field__c is a unique field in Contact object, then you can use the below logic
    if(!cons.isEmpty()){    
        for(Contact c : [Select Id, accountId, field__c From Contact where field__c in :cons])
            mapOfContacts.put(c.field__c,c); // Assuming field__c is a TEXT and UNIQUE field.
    }
    if(!mapOfContacts.isEmpty()){
        for(Opportunity op : trigger.new){
            if(String.isNotBlank(opp.field__c) && mapOfContacts.get(opp.field__c) <> null){
                op.Contact__c = mapOfContacts.get(opp.field__c).Id; // Aussuming Contact__c is a Custom lookup field
                op.accountId = mapOfContacts.get(opp.field__c).accountId; // Link Account Id to Oppotunity Account Field
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
**Syed**

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should know how a relationship works. here opportunity has an account, that is parent(lookup/master) for opportunity. in opportunity object there is a field account where account id is being stored. like

account Id: 0017F000007WRMFQA2(but you will always see a name for that account.)
so in coding(controller or trigger). we can call or use account id as seen in this picture.
[image: you can see here]

so now what you have to do :
1. find account id for that opportunity. Opportunity op.accountID
contact c.accountId

2. make a soql query for account
   account ac=select name from account where id=: op.accountID;
   account ac1=select name from account where id=: c.accountID;
3. now make changes.
   ac.name=ac1.name;

that's how you can change it.

**make sure don't use soql inside the loop. instead try to use map or set for that.**